# $z'=-\frac{2z}{z+1}$; find range of $z'$ when $z$ is imaginary

Tags: complex-numbers

> Suppose $z$ is a purely imaginary number and $z'=-\frac{2z}{z+1}$. Find the range $E$ of $z'$.
> Let $A=1$, $B=-1$ and $f$ the map that takes $M=z$ to $M'=z'$.

**Method 1:**

For every $z\ne-1$ we have
$$z'+1 =-\frac{2z}{z+1}+1=-1\frac{(z-1)}{(z+1)}$$
$$|z'+1|=\frac{|-1||z-1|}{|z+1|}$$
$$BM'=\frac{AM}{BM}$$
Thus when $z$ is imaginary, $M$ lies on the perpendicular bisector of $AB$ and so $BM'=1$. $E$ is the circle of radius 1 and centre $B$.

**Method 2:**
$$z'=-\frac{2z}{z+1}$$
$$z=-\frac{z'}{z'+2},\ z'\ne-2$$
When $z$ is imaginary, $\frac{z'}{z'-(-2)}$ is imaginary as well. Let $F=-2$ and $O=0$, then we have $OM'\perp FM'$ and $E$ the circle of diameter $OF$ excluding $F$.

This is the same circle as obtained in method 1 but excluding $-2$. If we try to solve it there:
$$-2=-\frac{2z}{z+1}$$
$$-2z-2=-2z$$
$$-2=0$$
which is absurd. So method 2 must be correct. Where is the mistake in method 1?

Comment: See this page for how to typeset http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference Enclose formulas in `$ ... $`. Some useful special characters for you: `\iff` to get $\iff$ and `\in` to get $\in$ and `\not = ` to get $\not=$.

Comment: thanks @Parcly Taxel  for your generosity  and help in formatting

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure if this answers but you should also exclude $\pm i\infty$ from your domain of definition. And this 'maps' to $-2$ which is therefore not achieved as a point in the range.

Comment: i'm afraid i haven't understood  if we ignore method 2 and think only about method 1 is there an intuitive explanation for why i should exclude i infinity